# Copying Long Text Area field between records in Apex

Tags: apex, field-mapping

When copying over fields all seem to works fine except for Text Area data type. Any help would be appreciated.

When copying over fields from one record to another using apex, fields of Text Area type seem to not get copied over.

```apex
For(quoteObj__c obj2: (quoteObj__c[])Trigger.new){
    obj1__c var1 = [SELECT field0, (SELECT field1, field2 FROM obj1__r)
    FROM obj1__c where field0 = obj2__c.id__c;]

    List<obj2> listFromObj1 = var1.obj1__r
 
    obj2__c.field1 = listFromObj1.get(0).field1
    obj2__c.field2 = listFromObj1.get(0).field2
}
```

For simplicity left out code where we store query in list and get values.
Field 1 is a string and works fine (also works if double)
Field 2 is Text Area and does not get copied over.
Does this require a special method or can this be accomplished in another way?

Comment: I think you need to provide the actual code because "copying" a field from one object to another definitely works regardless of the field type. Perhaps you are using `Security.stripInaccessible` and the contextual user doesn't have permission to write to the field?

Comment: (I meant to say "copying from one record to another" - but you can copy from a record for one object to a record for another object as long as the source and destination field types are compatible.)

Comment: Added a bit more context. I can see in the debugger that the expected value is being pulled from the listFromObj1 list. However in the obj2 page only field 1 is populated with the expected value. Field 2 is populated by a default value. Please let me know if any other information is needed

Comment: Your stripped down code is confusing. E.g. what is `obj2__c` in the `WHERE` clause, and is this actually handled via a static SOQL binding? While it's fine to consistently replace object and field names, please keep it as close to the original code as possible. You should also show the declaration of all relevant variables so we know their types (even if that is a replaced object name).

Comment: Added the declaration for obj2__c. Both objects are quotes. The goal is to copy over all fields from the original quote to the new quote after it has been renewed/amended.

Comment: Why not just load all the fields then use `SObject.clone`?